# Graphical user interface with TK - button position and actions

Tags: python, tk-toolkit

I started using TK in python to build a graphical interface for my program. 
I'm not able to fix 2 issues concerning (1) the position of a button in the window and (2) use a value of a radiobutton inside a fucntion.

This is my current code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("START")
root.geometry("500x200+500+200")

v = tk.IntVar()
v.set(0)  # initializing the choice

my_choise = [
("Basic",1),
("Advanced",2),
('Extreme',3)
]

def ShowChoice():
    print(v.get())

tk.Label(root, 
     text="""Choose your configuration:""",
     justify = tk.LEFT,
     padx = 20).pack()

val = 0
for val, choise in enumerate(my_choise):
    tk.Radiobutton(root,text=choise,padx = 20,variable=v,command=ShowChoice,value=val).pack(anchor=tk.W)


def star_program(value):
    os.system("ifconfig")

def open_comments_file():
    os.system("gedit /home/user/Desktop/comments.txt")

def open_links_file():
    os.system("gedit /home/user/Desktop/links.txt")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

open_file_c = tk.Button(frame, 
               text="Comments",
               command=open_comments_file)

open_file_f = tk.Button(frame, 
               text="Links",
               command=open_links_file)

button = tk.Button(frame, 
               text="Start",
               command=star_program(v.get()))

button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
open_file_f.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
open_file_c.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

slogan = tk.Button(frame,
               text="Cancel",
               command=quit)
slogan.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

I would like that the buttons "Links" and "Comments" were positioned below the radiobutton, one below the other. Now, all buttons are in line, but I would like to have "start" and "cancel" at the bottom of my window.

Then I tried to use the value of the radiobutton (choice) inside the star_program function. It does not work. My idea is, based on the choice selected in the radiobutton, perform different actions when I click the button "start":

```
    def star_program(value):
        if value == 0:
            os.system("ifconfig")
        else:
            print "Goodbye"
```

In addition, concerning "start" button, I have a strange behavior. The program runs "ifconfig" command also if I don't click on "start". And If I click "start" it does not perform any action.

Any suggestion? 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm assuming this is more like what you're after:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("START")
root.geometry("500x200+500+200")

v = tk.IntVar()
v.set(0)  # initializing the choice

my_choise = [
("Basic",1),
("Advanced",2),
('Extreme',3)
]

def ShowChoice():
    print(v.get())

tk.Label(root, 
     text="""Choose your configuration:""",
     justify = tk.LEFT,
     padx = 20).grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="nesw") # use grid instead of pack

root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

val = 0
for val, choise in enumerate(my_choise):
    tk.Radiobutton(root,text=choise,padx = 20,variable=v,command=ShowChoice,value=val).grid(column=1, row=val+1, sticky="nw")


def star_program(value):
    os.system("ifconfig")

def open_comments_file():
    os.system("gedit /home/user/Desktop/comments.txt")

def open_links_file():
    os.system("gedit /home/user/Desktop/links.txt")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky="nesw")

open_file_c = tk.Button(frame, 
               text="Comments",
               command=open_comments_file)

open_file_f = tk.Button(frame, 
               text="Links",
               command=open_links_file)

button = tk.Button(frame, 
               text="Start",
               command=lambda: star_program(v.get()))
# use lambda to create an anonymous function to be called when button pushed,
needed for functions where arguments are required

button.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky="nesw")
open_file_f.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="nesw")
open_file_c.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="nesw")

slogan = tk.Button(frame,
               text="Cancel",
               command=quit)
slogan.grid(column=4, row=3, sticky="nesw")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the "start" button is due to the function definition.
This is the right code that does not trigger any action if you don't click the button:

```
 button = tk.Button(frame, 
           text="Start",
           command=star_program)
```